# Dimensionality reduction using PCA for text classification

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pca, naivebayes

I am doing text classification of documents, I have around 4k categories and 1.1 million data samples.

I am constructing matrix which contain frequency of words in each document.
The sample of matrix looks as below

```
            X1     X2     X3        X4 
D1          1      1       0        1
D2          1      1       1        0
D3          1      1       0        0
D4          1      1       1        1
D5          0      0       1        0
D6          0      0       1        1
```

In above matrix, X1 and X2 are redundant features because they have same values in all rows.

First when I construct matrix from 1.1 million data, I will get huge matrix with 90k features.

To reduce matrix dimension, I am using dimension reduction technique PCA
 I have used TruncatedSVD to calculate PCA as I am using sparse matrix.

I am using Sckit learn implementation of PCA using below code

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
X = [[1,1,0,1], [1,1,1,0], [1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1]]
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=3)
svd.fit(X)  
X_new=svd.fit_transform(X)
```

The output of X_new is

```
array([[ 1.53489494, -0.49612748, -0.63083679],
   [ 1.57928583, -0.04762643,  0.70963934],
   [ 1.13759356, -0.80736818,  0.2324597 ],
   [ 1.97658721,  0.26361427, -0.15365716],
   [ 0.44169227,  0.75974175,  0.47717963],
   [ 0.83899365,  1.07098246, -0.38611686]])
```

This is the reduced dimension I got
I am giving X_new as input to Naive Bayes classifier.

```
clf = GaussianNB()
model=clf.fit(X_new, Y)
```

For 1.1 million sample I got below outputs:

```
No_of_components
(“n_components” parameter)           accuracy
   1000                                6.57%
   500                                 7.25%
   100                                 5.72%
```

I am getting very low accuracy,

Whether  above steps are correct?

What are the things I need to include further?

Comment: Do you know the distributions of the categories in your data?

Comment: I understand distribution as frequency of categories. As per that, among 4k categories around 400 categories have more than 500 data,around 750 categories have 100-400 data and remaining categories have data below 10

Comment: The danger is if your distribution is heavily skewed more importance will be given to those more frequent features. Consider further transformations on data if this is the case e.g. Z score.

Answer (score 2):

The accuracy is low, because **you lose most information during dimensionality rediction**.

You can check it with `sum(svd.explained_variance_ratio_ )`. This number, like `R^2`, measures precision of your model: it equals 1 if all information is preserved by SVD, and 0, if no information is preserved. In your case (3 dimensions of 90K features) I expect it to be of order 0.1%.

For your problem, I would recommend one of the two strategies.

**1**. Do not reduce dimensions mathematically. Instead, preprocess your text lingustically: drop the stop-words, stem or lemmatize the rest of words, and drop the words which occure less than `k` times. It will bring your dimensionality from 90K to something like 15K without serious loss of information.

On these features you can train a sparse model (like `SGDClassifier` with huge L1 penalty), which could bring the number of actually used features down to something like 1K with still a good accuracy. It sometimes helps to transform your word-counts with TF-IDF before feeding to a linear classifier.

**2**. Use a pre-trained dimensionality reducer, like `word2vec` or `fastText`, to extract features from your text. There exist pre-trained word2vec models in the Internet, for multiple languages, and several dimensionalities (like 200, 1000, etc.).

Comment: I always thought about `fastText` as a classifier, would you provide some source where I could see how to use it as a dimensionality reducer?

Comment: ```fastText``` first calculates word embeddings, and then uses them for classification. You need only the embeddings. See the discussion of producing embeddings of texts (instead of words) here: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/26